# How do I access environ variables in Django's wsgi?

Tags: django, wsgi

I am using this code to run django within twisted.

```
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
def wsgi_resource():
    pool = threadpool.ThreadPool()
    pool.start()
    # Allow Ctrl-C to get you out cleanly:
    reactor.addSystemEventTrigger('after', 'shutdown', pool.stop)

    real_wsgi_app = WSGIHandler()
    def my_wsgi_wrapper(environ, start_response):
        environ['somekey'] = "somevalue"
        return real_wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

    wsgi_resource = wsgi.WSGIResource(reactor, pool, my_wsgi_wrapper)
    return wsgi_resource

wsgi_root = wsgi_resource()
reactor.listenTCP(DJANGO_PORT, server.Site(wsgi_root))
```

in my django views, how do I access the key "somekey"? I hope to pass in an instance of a particular class which I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use request.META['somekey'].