# How to get environ in sub class of DefineBase of soaplib module?

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, soaplib

I am working with WSGI with mod_wsgi module. I was check some example on that and i get environ, start_response in each wsgi request.

Now I write one example from url http://soaplib.github.com/soaplib/2_0/pages/usermanager.html. I override wsgi.Application of soaplib and there I get environ variable. I also check code of DefineBase and in its **init** they are passing environ=None. So every time I get none. Is there any way to set environ in DefineBase so i get same environ which i get in wsgi.Application.

I check on stackoverflow but i get [How do I access environ variables in Django's wsgi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469586/how-do-i-access-environ-variables-in-djangos-wsgi). This way also possible in soaplib?

Thx for reply in advance ;)